# Boinc setting lower CPU usage at night

Tags: 20.04, cron, boinc

My computer is in the office where the cooler stops during the night.
It is okay to keep it running at 50 % of computing in the daytime.
I want to slow down the BOINC Computing into 10 % during the night for thermal and noise problems.

Somehow, GUI BOINC Manager can schedule its working time. I can live with that but if it is possible, `boinccmd` would do the reduced job for me. Perhaps use `crontab` but I couldn't come up with particular commands/shell scripts.

Comment: Looks like this might help you. https://www.tecmint.com/limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux-with-cpulimit-tool/

Comment: @PonJar, yes, I too think so. `ps -u boinc` and `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` We get process numbers and CPU temp. When CPU becomes hotter than 45°C, `cpulimit` regulates all the processes user boinc owns. I can write these things in human languages... Really bad at programming.